# facebook C# sdk: WebException if no internet connection after user logged in

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk, facebook-c#-sdk

I got this bug when using Facebook C# SDK 6.4/Facebook C# client 0.8 on Windows Phone 8. Here are the steps to reproduce this bug:

1. Log on to Facebook and save access token, then exit your application.
2. Disconnect your internet connection.
3. Reopen your application and pass the saved access token as parameter when making API calls.

Comment: Why is that a bug? If you have no connection, you get a WebException.

Comment: Actually it is a bug; in current design, a WebException or even another Exception should not surface from GetTaskAsync/PostTaskAsync of facebook.dll. They are all to be wrapped in PostCompleted/GetCompleted events.

And it seems the bug has been fixed. I built facebook.dll and facebook.client.dll from the latest source code and the bug was gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the bug has been fixed. I built facebook.dll and facebook.client.dll from the latest source code and the bug was gone.

Answer (score 0):

The `Facebook Access Token` acts like a temporary password to Facebook for the given `Facebook Application` with the given `Facebook User`. So, when you have a valid access token of a user, you can use Facebook API and can make Facebook API calls. Facebook API calls are requests sent from a device to Facebook. If you desire to issue a Facebook API call from your device, then of course, you need an internet connection to be able to send your request to Facebook's server. Without an internet connection creating the necessary infrastructure to send messages to Facebook's server you cannot expect to be able to send messages to Facebook's server.